# Round function differs in SQL and Snowflake

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Column Value = 1234.24**
SQL Query:

```
Cast(Round(Column_Name, 2, 1) AS Decimal (18,2)) As New_Column
```

gives me Value as **1234.23**, I understand it is truncating my last digit by 1 upto 2 decimals.
Snowflake Query:

```
Cast(Round(Column_Name),2) AS Decimal (18,2) As New_Column
```

gives me **1234.24** as we can use only 2 values
"Cast(Round(Column_Name)**,1.6**) AS Decimal (18,2) As New_Column" gives me **1234.23** as expected results,

Can please explain what is the relation of **(,2,1)** in SQL and **(,1.6)** in snowflake?
And are we allowed to use decimal values?
Is there any option that I can pass 3 values in snowflake as we are doing in SQL?

Comment: Please format your question... its unreadable as it is. I formatted it for you, but you overwrote my changes.

Comment: Also please provide a [mre] because `select Cast(Round(Column_Name, 2, 1) AS Decimal (18,2)) 
from (
  values (1234.24)
) x (Column_Name)` returns `1234.24` as expected

Comment: All your questions can be answered by the product documentation. I've edited your question, I beleive you had some syntax errors so I've don't my best to work out whatyou meant. Please fix if not right

Answer (score 0):

For Snowflake:

ROUND accepts arguments, and the second one is "scale expression" which indicated the number of digits the output should include after the decimal point. It should evaluate to an **integer** from -38 to +38. So you should not enter 1.6. Although it works now, someday it may be fixed and produce an error.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/round.html

For Microsoft SQL Server:

The third parameter indicated the function: When the function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

So when you use, "Round(Column_Name, 2, 1)", you truncate the rest of the digits instead of rounding the number. If you want to do the same thing, you can use the TRUNCATE function in Snowflake:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trunc.html

I suspect that you store your value as a floating-point number. Floating point numbers are approximate values. A floating point number might not round as expected.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#float-float4-float8